# Retrieve only alphabets from a specific column Postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have a field in a table where I have to get only alphabets and ignore numbers and special characters. How can I get that output?

## Example:

```
abc (234)454-4546

232-454-565 xyz

Ell # 83493
```

## Expected Output:

```
abc

xys

ell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC12345xyz','[^[:alpha:]]','','g');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Just noticed that I have a data as John 124 Perry. In this case how do I include just the space so that I get the output as John Perry. The query that you have provided gives JohnPerry. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I got it. SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC12345xyz','[^[:alpha:]]',' ','g'); adding an extra space for a "replacement string" solves this.